# What does the p-value returned in the array mean

Tags: python, chi-squared-test, p-value, scipy

I am working my way through various statistics using Python. One of the tests is the chi-squared test. On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test), it gives a table as an example that can be used to do the Chi-Squared test.

The table has a p-value of **0.000410**, and a critical value of **24.571**.

Using scipy.stats, I can get these values, which is good.

One of the scipy stats functionality is to compare the observed and expected results of an array, which generates a Power_divergenceResult.

The code I am using is:

```py
from scipy import stats as st
import numpy as np

# Create the lists containing the values for each of the collars
WC = [90, 60, 104, 95]                                                  # White Collar
BC = [30, 50, 51, 20]                                                   # Blue Colloar
NC = [30, 40, 45, 35]                                                   # No Collar

# Create the contingency table
collars = np.array([WC, BC, NC])                                        # Use the lists to create a 2D array

# Return the chi squared values, probability, degrees of freedom, and expected tables
test_stat, p_val, D_of_F, expect_t = st.chi2_contingency(collars)

print(st.chisquare(collars, expect_t))
```

This produces the following result:

> Power_divergenceResult(statistic=array([ 2.40088047, 12.66529198,  0.57885112,  8.92617929]), pvalue=array([0.30106164, 0.00177732, 0.74869352, 0.01152669]))

I have read the scipy explanation, but it does not cover more than 1D arrays. I am trying to understand what the p-value array in the Power_divergenceResults actually means.

Edit: the documentation for the chisquare function says of the value array:

> pfloat or ndarray:    The p-value of the test. The value is a float if ddof and the return value chisq are scalars.

Comment: You need to refer to the documentation, because "power divergence" is not a standard term or concept in statistics.

Comment: The documentation says of pvalue: The p-value of the test. The value is a float if ddof and the return value chisq are scalars. It does not explain the individual results.

Comment: The relevant documentation is at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.power_divergence.html#scipy.stats.power_divergence.